# Can WFC generate aesthetically pleasing maps?

Tags: procedural-generation, tilemap

Is wave function collapse actually capable of generating aesthetically pleasing tilemaps? Let's **very** roughly define "aesthetically pleasing" using an example from the world map of "Shovel Knight: Pocket Dungeon." Consider all aspects of the screenshots, including the objects like the trees or the clock (not just the terrain). Perhaps some of these can be place onto the map *after* the map has been generated, or lived entirely without.

Nevertheless, either by itself or in combination with other procedural generation techniques, is WFC capable of generating something close to this caliber? So far, I've only seen trivial results of WFC that very much resemble patterns (like the visuals in `ExUtumno`'s [WFC readme](https://github.com/mxgmn/WaveFunctionCollapse)), and I'm concerned that when used in production, WFC will not be visually provocative. Am I digging into the wrong approach?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of asking "Does [tool] solve [problem]?" it's usually nore productive to ask "How do I solve this [problem]?". Then you can get answers not limited to binary yes/no about a single tool, but actionable "how" advice for applying one or more tools you might not even have considered yet. It also helps avoid subjectivity around what counts as "aesthetically pleasing". [Caves of Qud uses WFC in conjunction with other techniques](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=AdCgi9E90jw) to make maps that some would call aesthetically pleasing while others would strongly disagree. 

Comment: You linked a tool that use WFC to build stuff. What happened when you tried it? How did it differ from your target expectations?