# How to generate visually stunning tilemaps?

Tags: procedural-generation, tilemap

I previously asked [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/208104/can-wfc-generate-aesthetically-pleasing-maps?noredirect=1#comment379602_208104) question but I don't think it was well phrased, so I want to rephrase the question.

---

I want to generate tilemaps that resembles the pixel art world maps from "Shovel Knight: Pocket Dungeon". I will have access to the tiles and objects shown in the pictures without rotation.

So far, my plan is to use WFC, but in multiple stages. For example, I'd first use it to generate landmarks, say, a large castle, place it somewhere on the map. From there feed it to the WFC again to generate the terrains, then feed it to the WFC again to generate the objects on top of the terrains, like the trees or the giant clock.

This is my plan but I'm new to procedural generation so I want to see if anyone have suggestions or advice on whether if this would work or if there are better algorithms I could look into? My goal is to create tilemaps that are visually amazing with lots of diversity.

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like this should have been an edit to the linked previous question instead of a new post. How is this question substantially different?

Comment: It sounds like you have a plan for how to approach this problem already. What happens when you try to implement your plan? Does it meet your goals, or are there specific ways in which it falls short, where we can help you improve? It's not clear to me from two examples what criteria would be used to rate whether a result is "visually amazing" or what kinds of diversity are desired so it's difficult to suggest algorithms to achieve these goals without more details about what specifically you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm voting to close because it appears to be a rephrasing of your prior question: [Can WFC generate aesthetically pleasing maps?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/208104/can-wfc-generate-aesthetically-pleasing-maps) If you need to change your question, please [edit it](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/editing) instead of reposting.